# what is the difference between BFC and stacking context?

Tags: css

these makes me so confuse.

what is the difference between  Block_Formatting_Context and stacking_context ?

thank you !

Comment: Have you found the answer yet? would appreciate if you either accepted eshan's or my solution if these helped you ;) appreciate the review in advance!

Answer (score 1):

A `stacking context` consists of seven different layers (from bottom to top):

- the background and borders of the element that establishes the stacking context
- the stacking contexts of descendants with negative stack levels
- block-level descendants in the normal flow
- floated descendants and their contents
- inline-level descendants in the normal flow
- positioned descendants whose z-index is auto or 0
- the stacking contexts of descendants with positive stack levels

A new `block formatting context` can be created by adding any one of the necessary CSS conditions like `overflow: scroll, overflow: hidden, display: flex, float: left, or display: table` to the container. Though any of the above mentioned conditions can create a `block formatting context`, there will also be some other effects like:

- `display`: table may create problems in responsiveness
- `overflow`: scroll may show unwanted scrollbars
- `float`: left will push the element to the left, with other elements wrapping around it
- `overflow`: hidden will clip elements that overflow

Answer (score 0):

> A block formatting context is a part of a visual CSS rendering of a Web page. It is the region in which the layout of block boxes occurs and in which floats interact with each other.
>
> Read More : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context

And

> Stacking context is the three-dimensional conceptualization of HTML elements along an imaginary z-axis relative to the user who is assumed to be facing the viewport or the webpage. HTML elements occupy this space in priority order based on element attributes.
>
> read More : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context